# Rails / Simple form for "selected" option stopped working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, simple-form, selected

I've got a problem with the `selected` option in simple_form.

Historically you could do something like that:

```
f.association :city, label: "City", collection: City.where(country: "France"), label_method: :name, value_method: id, selected: City.first.id
```

It suddenly stop working and I can't figure out why. No matter what I try (`City.last.id`, `City.first.id`, `City.find_by(name: "Paris")`), it keeps taking in first value of my collection from now on

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 f.association :city, label: "City", collection: City.where(country: "France"),:selected => City.first.id, label_method: :name, value_method: id
```

or

```
f.association :city, label: "City", collection: City.where(country: "France"),:selected => City.where(country: "France").first.id, label_method: :name, value_method: id
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Gabbar but it's not working. It keeps picking the first value of my collection